# how do I group or Bundled the virtual product for a warranty service?

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product, grouped-products, virtual-products

I have 800 Simple electronic Products. what is the best way to implement virtual product as a warranty Service based on product price? Group Product or Bundle product doesn't seem to be a good option. it seems that I would have to do all 800 items individually, would need to change it to group or bundle configure it. doesn't seem too efficient. Am I missing something here there has to be a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to show options like this one:

[image]

If yes, you can set Customizable Options as my following screenshots:

[image]

Comment: I would love to be able do this - the problem with this method is I would have to do all 800 products individually....is there any way i can do this with bulk ?